# Horizontally Splited Emacs window modifies both windows

Tags: emacs

I split a file on Emacs using `C-x 2`.
When I modify the top window, the bottom window gets modified simultaneously.
How can I modify the top window and not the bottom?

Comment: You may have confused the concepts of Windows, buffers and files. Although you split Windows, they show the same buffer and changes are synchronized between the two Windows. If you really want to, you need to create a new buffer or file with the same content.

Comment: @TianshuWang: Consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the remind. I'm still not very good at drawing the line between an answer and a comment

Comment: Maybe ask on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You may have confused the concepts of Windows, buffers and files. Although you split Windows, they show the same buffer and changes are synchronized between the two Windows. If you really want to, you need to create a new buffer or file with the same content.